# Unity Custom Editor - Add Data Fields Based on Derived Type

Tags: unity-game-engine

Final goal: create a custom editor that will let me select from a list of types and then enter additional parameters specific to that type.

To this end, I have created a pure data type, let's call it `BasicData`, with a `SpecificData` parameter of an abstract base type, let's call it `ExtraData`. The idea is to have the type information in `BasicData` (enum value), and then populate the `SpecificData` field in the custom editor code so that when I change selection a new object from a class derived from `ExtraData`. Then its values can be further edited by additional fields created for that specific type, as shown [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/417837/change-inspector-variables-depending-on-enum.html).

I started doing the above, but I ran into problems trying to get the actual object being edited in order to set the `SpecificData` property. My classes are not Unity objects or scripts, and I'd rather not turn them into such just for this. I might be able to use reflection to do this but then changes in the editor won't take effect while it runs, from what I understand.

What is the best way to accomplish this?